# disk space usage by process in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Is there any way to know how much disk space currently running process is using? I have checked `ps` and `top` command but could not find out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use atop command. You can install via

```
sudo apt-get install atop
```

Then you can execute following command

```
atop -MD
```

-RDDSK and -WRDSK are the parameters you need to check

Here is the reference link

http://www.atoptool.nl/screenshots.php